# Slack File/Snippet Upload Will Not Expand Inline - Works Externally

Tags: slack, slack-api

When using `https://slack.com/api/files.upload` to upload a file/snippet to a channel, the snippet successfully shows up in the desired channel, and contains the correct title and filename. However, when clicking the `Click to expand inline` button, significantly fewer lines show up than were uploaded.

However, clicking the external link button on the file/snippet, taking me to the file in the web browser, all the lines are there and the file looks normal:

**When it is successfully posted:**

[image: Here is the file/snippet showing that it is 301 lines, ready to expand.]

**Clicking this expand button:**

[image: The snippet shows as expanded but only displays 5 lines.]

**In the browser when clicking the square with the arrow coming out of the top-right button:**

[image: In the browser, 100% of the lines show up.]

All 301 lines show up here.

Is there something that I have to do to ensure all the lines show up in the Slack clients? Even refreshing Slack does not work!

**EDIT:** Slack’s support says that [this is a known bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uflds.jpg).